# Calculating colours in a colour map

Tags: colors, statistics

Suppose I have some data to be displayed on a bar chart, and each bar will be coloured according to its height.

Say the bars range in height from *a* to *b*.

What is the best way of calculating the numbers in a continuous colour map so that *a* is assigned a set of RGB values, *a+1* is assigned a set of RGB values all the way through to *b*. The data is continuous.

The colours assigned need to be such that if data point 1 has value *x* and data point 2 has a value close to *x*, the colours assigned to data points 1 and 2 will be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much, depending on what program you're using to do it in, it's fairly straight forward.  Think of having 3 columns R G and B (they could be stored multiple different ways).

Pure red is 255 with G and B being 0.  Same goes for pure green and blue with their respective colors.  Then it's just a matter of covering every possible color you want.

A sample color chart is [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=rgb+color+codes&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=alz4T-ZB477QAeW00fYG&ved=0CGkQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=963#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=rgb+color+chart&revid=2016809888&sa=X&ei=blz4T9O4EqXD0QHenJTfBg&ved=0CEgQgxY&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fd6b265ac54d034a&biw=1280&bih=963)

Another option is to use the [HSV color system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and then convert it to RGB if you really need to have RGB.  I personally find working with HSV to be easier and more concise when generating a whole array of usable colors.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! I was really struggling to make the colours continuous and keep it tidy mathematically, but using the cylindrical coordinate system that HSV provides is really awesome.